# navigationbar missing after using UISearchController

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

i have a `UICollectionViewController` where i am showing list of task which is working fine, recently i tried to implement a `UISearchBar` for my `TaskController` after implementing that, when i try to launch any new `viewcontroller` by clicking on row inside my `TaskController` the newly launched view controller does not have `UINavigationBar` so i cant move back to my task list again. see following `TaskController` with task list:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2nLH.png)

in above screen shot there is a star icon when user click on that, I launch following view controller which have a navigation bar(**note:** **I have click directly without filtering records thats why i can see the navigation bar here.**). `UIViewController` with `UINavigationBar`
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReW7a.png)

this is what i get when i click on star icon after filtering data with search bar.
[navigation bar gone missing here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmbG9.png)
so i can not go back to task list controller also when i change a tab from below and come back the view controller got destroyed and i get a black screen with tab bar.

following code i have used to implement search bar which have the problem please help me to figure it out.

```
 let taskSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //set taskSearchController

    taskSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    taskSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.searchController = taskSearchController
    getTaskList(){

    }
}
```

following method gives the filtered data from tasklist

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, !searchText.isEmpty  else{

        self.taskList = self.originalTaskist
        collectionView?.reloadData()
        return
    }
    taskList = originalTaskist.filter({ task -> Bool in
            return task.name!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    })
    collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true you can use this to show navigation

Comment: You are using navigation bar as search view. after completion of your search method you can unhide the navigation bar using above comment 's code.

Comment: found the solution we need to set `definesPresentationContext = true` in a `viewdidLoadMethod` solution is available at [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) which says **"setting definesPresentationContext on your view controller to true, you ensure that the search bar does not remain on the screen if the user navigates to another view controller while the UISearchController is active.
"**

Answer (score 2):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This prevents the search bar to make trouble on pushed view controllers
    definesPresentationContext = true

    //...
}
```

Put `definesPresentationContext = true` inside of your View Controller that shows the search bar (the `UICollectionViewController` in your case.

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext) doesn't explain very well why this is working. [This blog post](https://thomasdenney.co.uk/blog/2014/10/5/uisearchcontroller-and-definespresentationcontext/) explains it a little better.